# I wrote a ajax request.But the url of ajax and the actual url is different

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/api/news/'+ obj.id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      $('.detail-title').append(data.article_title)
      $('.detail-date').append(data.publish_date.slice(0, 10))
      $('.detail-content').append($(data.article_content))
    }
```

but the actual request url is `http://www.example.com/news/6/`

Comment: Probably a redirect happening on the server side. This isn't really a client-side issue that anyone here can help you with

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i do not make a redirect happening on the server side.And how i can find  - Rory McCrossan. I am new here.

Comment: Check your *rendered* output (assuming this is not in a .js file and you have some server-side tech generating your page).  Could be a url rewrite when rendering (so it's calling what's in the page, but what's in the page is wrong).